# Check Component Dependency

Tags: magento2, composer, conflict

I am getting this component dependency error

[image]

I have referred also referred other question regarding the same but could not find suitable problem solving answer.

**Are there any general checkpoints(list of files which needs to be configured/ or required libraries) which should be kept in mind for solving this particular error?**

Can we solve this error by modifying composer.json ? IF YES, then how?

Comment: Did you solved your issue?

Comment: Solved by hit and trial, and configuring again..
But could not find proper steps